# Metrics 'accuracy' in keras throw Error 'Incompatible shape' when tackle segmentation task

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dataset

I use Keras to tackle segmentation task.
The groundtruth maps are binary images, noting that black represents background and white represents objects.
So I use datagenerator in Keras as follow, before that I have set value 0 to pixels of background and value 1 to objects:

```
train_label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    horizontal_flip= True,
)
train_label_generaror = train_label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=os.path.join(FLAGS.dataset_dir, FLAGS.cropped_dir, "training",
                           FLAGS.labels_folder_name),
    target_size=(FLAGS.resize_size, FLAGS.resize_size),
    class_mode= None, 
    color_mode= 'grayscale',
    batch_size= FLAGS.batch_size,
    seed = FLAGS.seed,
    shuffle= False
)
```

And model.compile function details like this:

```
sgd = SGD(lr= FLAGS.lr, decay=FLAGS.decay, momentum=FLAGS.momentum, 
          nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer= sgd,
              loss = losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['acc', miou])
```

The model.output is a probability map.
My question is: When I train the model there is an Error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [602112] vs. [12,224,224]
 [[Node: metrics/acc/Equal = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](metrics/acc/Reshape, metrics/acc/Cast)]]
 [[Node: metrics/miou/confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1/_167 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_544_m...t/Switch_1", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I try to change loss to 'binary_crossentropy' and output.activation to 'sigmoid', then it works.
So I want to know what makes this mistake.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in METRICS 'acc',  when I delete the 'acc' it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying different ways, and analysis **confusion_matrix**, I have solved the problem.
The code is as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import confusion_matrix
def custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, nb_classes):
    class_labels= K.reshape(y_true, shape=[-1])
    class_pred = K.resshape(y_pred, axis= -1)
    class_pred = K.reshape(class_pred, shape=[-1])

    confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(labels= class_labels,
                                        prediction= class_pred,
                                        num_classes= nb_classes)
    TP = 0
    all = 0
    for class_index in range(0, nb_classes):
        TP += confusion_matrix[class_index, class_index]
        all += confusion_matrix[class_index]

    return K.sum(TP) / K.sum(all)
```

By customized accuracy metrics, it works.